# Dynamic privileges in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, airbyte

I'm using Airbyte to sync data into a Postgres server. I want to use a dedicated Postgres user for this purpose, so that it can't read or write on anything else outside of its intendend scope.

All the data synced by Airbyte will come into a single database, but in multiple schemas. So, if Airbyte fetches data from databases Alice, Bob and Charlie, the schemas in the target Postgres database will be `sync_alice`, `sync_bob` and `sync_charlie`.

I'm facing issues with creating the right `GRANT` statements for the `airbyte_user` that I would like Airbyte to use when accessing the Postgres server. What I would like to do is to provide this user with:

- The ability to create new schemas.
- The ability to create, select, insert, update and delete on tables *ONLY* in schemas that follow the naming pattern `sync_<whatever>`.
- For clarity, I don't want the user to be able to read or modify anything outside of schemas that don't follow the `sync_<whatever>` convention.

I'm having a hard time finding a way to use some kind of wildcard in the `GRANT` statements. I was hoping something like this would work:

```
GRANT CREATE, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE postgres TO airbyte_user;
GRANT CREATE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA 'sync_*' TO airbyte_user;
```

But postgres complains on the second statement syntax.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want, or am I doomed to only give my `airbyte_user` the permissions on the different `sync_<whatever>` schemas one by one as I create them?

Thanks

Comment: You can create any schema if you  have `CREATE` on the database. But permissions on the schema don't govern what a user is allowed to do with a table. For that, you must `GRANT` privileges on the tables itself.